# Difference between natural response and forced response?

Tags: impulse-response, transfer-function

### Reference

**Second** post on [EdaBoard.com](http://www.edaboard.com/thread57404.html)

> Time response of a system is the time evolution of the variables. In
> circuits, this would be the waveforms of voltage and current versus
> time.
>
> Natural response is the system's response to initial conditions with
> all external forces set to zero. In circuits, this would be the
> response of the circuit with initial conditions (initial currents on
> inductors and initial voltage on capacitors for example) with all the
> independent voltages set to zero volts (short circuit) and current
> sources set to zero amps (open circuit). The natural response of the
> circuit will be dictated by the time constants of the circuit and in
> general roots of the characteristics equation (poles).
>
> Forced response is the system's response to an external stimulus with
> zero initial conditions. In circuits, this would just be the response
> of the circuit to external voltage and current source forcing
> function... **[continue reading](http://www.edaboard.com/thread57404.html)**

### Questions

1. How can there be even a natural response? Something has to be inputted to create an output? The way I see it is like turning of the main water line and then turning on your faucet and expecting water to come out.
2. How can we `v(t)` (from the link above) be solved for if we don't know `dv(dt)` in order to find the natural response?
3. If you can please expand on the 2 concepts (natural response and forced response) by explaining their differences in Layman's terms, it would be lovely.